# Normality of the sequence of functions $f_n(z) = z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(z) = z^n$.

(a) We consider $f_n$’s as functions on $Ω = {|z| > 1}$.
Show that $\{f_n\}_{n≥1}$ is not normal for the distance in $\mathbb{C}$, but it converges for the chordal distance on $\mathbb{C}^*$ uniformly on compact sets.

My attempt: Let $K$ be a compact set in $Ω$. We can put $r = \max|z|$ for $z \in Ω$.

Then $\max|f_n(z)-1| = \max|z^n - 1| = r^n -1$,
$r^n$ goes to infity as $n$ goes to infinity, therefore $\{f_n\}_{n≥1}$ is not normal for the distance in $\mathbb{C}$.

If we look at the chordal distance on the other hand we get that

$$\max \frac{2|f_n(z)|-0}{\sqrt{1+|f_n(z)|^2}\sqrt{1+|0|^2}}
= \max \frac {2|z|^n}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2n}}} = \frac{2r^n}{\sqrt{1+r^{2n}}}.$$
This goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinty since denominator goes to $∞$ quicker than the numerator.

Therefore $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets for the chordal distance on $\mathbb{C}^*$.

(b) $f_n$ are functions on $\mathbb{C}$
show that $\{f_n\}$ is not spherically normal.

My approach: my attempt was to look at the spherical derivatives $f_n^{
♯}(z)$ and show that they are not uniformly bounded.

I was wondering if someone could check my approaches because I'm pretty sure they are wrong but I don't really get how else to approach these questions, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MartinR thank you so much!! that really helped

Comment: "This goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinty since denominator goes to $∞$ quicker than the numerator." This is not true: $$
\frac{{2r^n }}{{\sqrt {1 + r^{2n} } }} = \frac{{2r^n }}{{r^n \sqrt {r^{ - 2n}  + 1} }} = \frac{2}{{\sqrt {r^{ - 2n}  + 1} }} \to \frac{2}{{\sqrt {0  + 1} }} = 2.
$$